# Java math conversion

Tags: java, c++

I have this code in C++

```
float result = -log(result)/0.5231-1.0;
```

And I converted that into Java code like this

```
float result = (float) (-Math.log(result)/0.5231-1.0);
```

Is this correct way to convert the c++ code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the first C++ statement is illegal. You are defining `result`, and while initializing you use `result`.

But yes, the Java code does the same as the C++ code, if we ignore the irrelevant errors.

Answer (score 0):

That is not really a question, but yes, the code you've written in Java does the same as your C++ code.

I wouldn't suggest converting big pieces of code from C++ to java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. But you need to declare "result" above in code.

```
float result = ... ;    
result = (float) (-Math.log(result)/0.5231-1.0);
```

BTW there are many java libs for math purposes. E.g. http://commons.apache.org/math/